# What are the effects of each attribute?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are stats outside of your primary worth getting at all?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/are-stats-outside-of-your-primary-worth-getting-at-all)
>   [What are the properties of each stat point?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69597/what-are-the-properties-of-each-stat-point)

What do Dexterity, Strength, Intelligence and Vitality do?
Do they have different effect in each class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strength increases Armor by the amount of Strength you have, and increases Barbarian damage  the amount of Strength you have as a % amount. Meaning if you have 100 STR you'll have 100 armor and 100% extra damage as a Barbarian.

Dexterity increases Dodge chance, and increases Monk and Demon Hunter Damage just like Barbarian's STR

Intellect increases Magic Resistance based on total INT. For Example, 1111 INT would give you 111.1 Magic Resistance. Intellect also increases Wizard and Witch Doctor damage just like Barbarian's STR.

Vitality increases health.

Comment: Int also increases magic resistance.

Comment: Good catch. Was doing that off the top of my head, not surprised I missed it, lol.

Comment: what's so wrong with this question that I get -1 for each +1 you get?

Comment: @Roberto I think you get -1s because all you have to do is to hover your mouse over each stat in the game. All the information listed by Klokworkk you can find there. Lack of research I'd say! Klokworkk gave the *correct* answer; that's why he got +1s.

Answer (score 1):

You can mouse over the stats on your character screen and the game will tell you exactly what they do for your class.