# What are the properties of each stat point?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know in Diablo III you can no longer assign your attributes, and I know there are four attributes present in the game:

1. Strength
2. Vitality
3. Dexterity
4. Intelligence

**What are the stat bonuses from each point assigned to each attirbute?** For example, I know strength adds to a Barbarians damage. I want to be able to know at a glance when dealing with items that add + to stats what they will be doing for my character and what stats I should be looking for based on builds I may be thinking of.

Comment: Why is someone trolling me downvoting my questions today? Please explain how this question violates any of the SE rules.

Comment: well, for one thing, this is a dupe.

Comment: It wasn't me, but it could be because of [this duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68638/5291) which is sitting at a -5 vote.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz not sure if duplicated, but related for sure.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Voting to close for a duplicate VS downvoting are not synonmous. Now if the question was literally poorly presented then its fair to downvote it. I did give a quick search and didn't find that.

Comment: [Are stats outside of your primary worth getting at all?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/are-stats-outside-of-your-primary-worth-getting-at-all) Talk about the different aspect of each status in different class. This one is more complete and talk about all status and their meaning. If you could say. the `Are stats outside of your primary worth getting at all?` question should be Dupe of this one in my opinion.

Comment: @emerica I didn't Downvote. I'm merely providing a hypothesis.

Comment: While this is a duplicate question, the question / answers here are *much* stronger, so I'm actually going to close the earlier (downvoted) question as a dupe of this one.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yeah I know it wasn't you haha, I just feel like someone is deliberatley downvoting me today. That was three in a row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Strength**

- Each point increases **Barbarian's** damage by 1%
- Each point increases armor by 1 **for every class**

**Vitality**

- Each point increases your Life (dependent on your level, higher level=more vitality per point. See below for formulas) **for every class**

> Life when player level < 35 = 36 + 4 × Level + 10 × Vitality
>
> Life when player level ≥ 35 = (level - 25) × Vitality

[Source](http://mmo-mechanics.com/swtor/forums/Thread-Diablo-3-formula-list)

**Intelligence**

- Each point increases **Wizard's** and **Witch Doctor's** damage by 1%
- Each point gives .1 to all resists **for every class**

**Dexterity**

- Each Point also increases **Monk's** Armor by 1 with the Seize The Initiative passive unlocked at level 20.
- Each point increases **Monk's** and **Demon Hunter's** Damage by 1%
- Each point increases chance to dodge **for every class**

  ```
    Dex range     Dodge% per point of Dex

   1    - 100             0.100

   101  - 500             0.025

   501  - 1000            0.020

   1001 - 8000            0.010
  ```

[Source](http://clicktoloot.com/p/combat.html#dodge)

Comment: Do you have the math about the vitality ?

Comment: @MichelAyres I've added the formula to the post. Source: http://mmo-mechanics.com/swtor/forums/Thread-Diablo-3-formula-list

Comment: Dexterity math taken from : http://www.clicktoloot.com/p/combat.html#dodge

Comment: I made an edit, hope you like it.

Comment: @MichelAyres Thanks a bunch! I'm not very good with formatting so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Neither I'm. sometimes I got luck. that all =D

Answer (score 3):

From Diablo 3's [Game Guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/fundamentals#attributes):

- Strength: The primary attribute for Barbarians. Strength increases Barbarian damage, and increases Armor for all classes.
- Dexterity: The primary attribute for Demon Hunters and Monks. Dexterity increases Demon Hunter and Monk damage, and increases Dodge Chance for all classes.
- Intelligence: The primary attribute for Witch Doctors and Wizards. Intelligence increases Witch Doctor and Wizard damage, and increases resistances for all classes.
- Vitality: Increases Life, the amount of damage you can take before dying.
- Armor: Decreases the amount of damage you take from enemy attacks.
- Damage: Indicates the average amount of damage you deal with your attacks. Damage is derived from your equipped weapons, primary attribute, attack speed, and critical hit chance.

Primary class abilities provide an additional 1% damage per point.

Strength gives 1 point of armor per each point.

Every point of Intelligence grants .1 to all resistances.

As for knowing at a glance what items will be doing by adding stats, you can check the tool tip when comparing an item to what you have equipped, and it will show exact changes to all of your abilities, from damage to protection to health.  Positive changes will be shown in green, and negative changes in red.

Answer (score 1):

For all characters:

- **Strength** - adds to armor, +1 AC/per point (not sure)
- **Inteliigence** - add to resistances, +0.1 resist all/each
- **Dexterity**: add to Dodge, varying amounts based on your dodge value
- **Vitality**: health - will update after checking if the gains are different across classes

Besides that, each character has a main stat that adds to their damage and is listed in the character select screen.

- STR: Barbarian
- INT: Wizard, Witch Doctor
- DEX: Monk, Demon Hunter